# Drop down list in a table

Tags: php, html-table

Why does my dropdown list seperate in the table to diff columns. Example I want 3 options to be displayed in the dropdown list. These are data from my database.

**Eg:** `company a, company b` to be displayed on the drop down list.

Instead now only one option `(company a)` is available on the drop list and `(company b)` is displayed on the next row of the table instead of together on a single drop down list.

```
  <?
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT admin_no, name, GPA, gender, job_details.job_title, job_details.no_of_vacancy FROM student_details, job_details ORDER BY `GPA` DESC ");

            $result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT job_title FROM job_details;");
            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
              {

                while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
                  {


              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td bgColor=white>" . $row['admin_no'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td bgColor=white>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td bgColor=white>" . $row['GPA'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td bgColor=white>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>"; 
              echo "<td><select name='ddl' onclick='if(this.value != '') { myform.submit(); }'><option value='". $row2['job_title'] ."'> ". $row2['job_title'] ."</option></td>";
              echo "</tr>";
              }
              }
            echo "</table>";



    ?>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, You have missed to close `</select>` tag, I have rewritten the code i.e moved  `<option>` tag generation above table generation section. So that to avoid unneccessary looping.

```
    <?php
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT admin_no, name, GPA, gender, job_details.job_title, job_details.no_of_vacancy FROM student_details, job_details ORDER BY `GPA` DESC ");

            $result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT job_title FROM job_details");
            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

             /*options sections start*/
            $options= '';
            while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
            {
                $options .='<option value="'. $row2['job_title'] .'"> '. $row2['job_title'] .'</option>';
            }
            /*options sections end*/

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
              {     
                  echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td bgColor=white>" . $row['admin_no'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td bgColor=white>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td bgColor=white>" . $row['GPA'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td bgColor=white>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>"; 
                  echo "<td><select name='ddl' onclick='if(this.value != '') { myform.submit(); }'>".$options."</select></td>";
                  echo "</tr>";              
              }
            echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
          {

          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td bgColor=white>" . $row['admin_no'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td bgColor=white>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td bgColor=white>" . $row['GPA'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td bgColor=white>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>"; 

          echo "<td><select name='ddl' onclick='if(this.value != '') { myform.submit(); }'>";
       while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
              {
         echo "<option value='". $row2['job_title'] ."'> ". $row2['job_title'] ."</option>";
            }
         echo "</select></td>";
          echo "</tr>";

          }
```